# Get calendars from owncloud with C# UWP app using caldav

Tags: c#, uwp, owncloud, caldav

I have a raspberry pi with windows 10 IOT and remote program it with visual studio in c# from my windows 10 PC. I now want to show the calendars from my online owncloud on a display connected to my raspberry pi. Now I have the problem to read the calendar informations from my owncloud.

The only code I found online is this link: [this: https://ovaismehboob.com/2014/03/30/sync-calendar-events-using-caldav/](https://ovaismehboob.com/2014/03/30/sync-calendar-events-using-caldav/)

The problem now is, that I have to use a UWP app, because of my raspberry and this code is not usable in UWP. I have read that I need a System.Net.Http webclient, but I have no idea how to do this.

So please can anybody give me a sample code of how I can read the calendar informations from owncloud by using caldav?

Comment: In UWP, I suggest you use the HttpClient of the [Windows.Web.Http](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/httpclient) namespace to send http request.

Comment: Yes, I know, but how is this done. I need some sample code.

Comment: There are no exist code for what you request. I think the problem is that what you want to sync? Say you have a cloud server, can you send the info you need as a xml to your cloud server and then you can use your web api to get the xml info from the cloud?